# parse: query a project to see if a table name exists

Tags: parse-platform

I am a relative newbie to parse (and IOS) so I hope that this question is legitimate. I am using parse tables as events with entries into the table being all who have joined the event. I want to be able to query my project to see if an event (table name) exists.  Is there a way to query the entire project to see if a PF object exists based on the table name? Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Extremely inefficient and horrible data base design. Make one table. Name it Events. In that table, make these columns. eventID (Unique, primary key),   attendingMembers (array of pointers to Users who are attending). Read about designing databases and different types in Parse .

Comment: Later you can simply query by eventID, if you get a result, the event exists. If you get 0 objects in return, it means no such event exists.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you are creating a table by event, you will end up having as many tables as events, which is not what you want. In my opinion, you should be creating a table with all events, then another table with all the persons joining the events. On this second table, you will use a Pointer to the first table. This way, you can query all events in the first table and see if a particular event exists.